# How does use an arduino like a A/D converter for convert 3 analogue signal from 3 poteciometer to a raspberry?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm developing a control system in my `raspberry`. Unfortunately, `raspberry` doesn't have any analogue port. Can I use `arduino` to convert 
 signal from analogue to digital, and send this signal into a I/O digital port from `anduino` to `raspberry? Is that possible?

Comment: You can't send an analog value through digital pins on Rpi. A simple solution is to use Serial to send values to Pi. Is it what you want?

Comment: yes but, in a serial i only can send one value or i can send more value?

Comment: my plan was receive the analog signal in arduino and transforms here in a digital signal and after send it by Digital port to rasberry

Comment: You can send and receive as many data as you want.

Comment: Could you give me a little example to how do it with two value of different potenciometer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send an analog value through digital pins on Raspberry Pi but you can use serial communication between the two.

On the Arduino side, you need to first read the analog data (value of potentiometers), serialize them (like convert it to a string) and then send it through the serial port to the Pi. On the Pi side, just receive the value and just convert them to a float value.

Follow the connection like in [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInput) and remember to change the pin names according to your connection.

Arduino Code:

```
// definition of analog pins
int analogPin1 = A0;
int analogPin2 = A1;
int analogPin3 = A2;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

// a function to read values and convert them to String
String read()
{
  // a variable to hold serilize data of values that need to be sent
  String result = "";
  // convert each value to string
  String analogPin1_value = String(analogRead(analogPin1), 3);
  String analogPin2_value = String(analogRead(analogPin2), 3);
  String analogPin3_value = String(analogRead(analogPin3), 3);
  // result would become something like "1.231,59.312,65.333"
  result = analogPin1_value + "," + analogPin2_value + "," + analogPin3_value;
  return result;
}

void loop()
{
  // send values with one second delay
  Serial.println(read());
  delay(1000);
}
```

Pi code:

```
import serial

# remember to set this value to a proper serial port name
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
ser.open()
# flush serial for unprocessed data
ser.flushInput()
while True:
    result = ser.readline()
    if result:
        # decode result
        result = result.decode()
        print("new command:", result)
        # split results
        values = list(map(float, result.split(",")))
        print("Converted results:", values)
```